# I've made a 32GB Kali live boot on a 64GB usb but I can't see both partitions

Tags: linux, kali-linux, liveusb

When i plug in the USB I can only see and access the kali live boot partition and transfer files in and out like normal. But i want that partition to be hidden and the other 32GB partition to be visible and accessible (while now it isn't).

Comment: What data is in your fstab?

Comment: If you open the USB drive in Disks, are there *two formatted partitions*, or is there *one partition of 32 GB and 32 GB of empty, unallocated, unformatted space*? If the later, just format that space FAT32 to access it. However, I know of no way to hide the active partition.

Comment: In windows I could see two partitions but one was unnamed (not free). In Ubuntu, I see a 31GB FAT named KALI LIVE, and a 32GB Ext3 named persistance.
I thought persistance was gonna be withing the FAT one.